# Azure kubernetes service creation issue

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-virtual-network, azure-aks

I'm creating kubernetes service in Azure with Advanced Networking options where I've selected particular vNet and Subnet for it.

I'm getting error as below:

```
{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The template deployment failed with error: 'Authorization failed for template resource '<vnetid>/<subnetid>/Microsoft.Authorization/xxx' of type 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/providers/roleAssignments'. The client '<emailid>' with object id 'xxx' does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' at scope '/subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/<rgid>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<vnetid>/subnets/<subnetid>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxx'.'."}
```

I've got contributor role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the existing answer is not exactly true, you can get away with the `Owner` role, obviously, but you only need `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` over the scope of the subnet (might be vnet, didnt test this). which helps lock down security little bit. You'd need a custom role to do that. In case you dont want to go for the custom role, existing answer will be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

As per the following article, you will need Owner privileges over the vNet to change access to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#built-in-role-descriptions

Comment: No.  Contributor doesn't allow you to change permissions on the vNet.  If Owner permissions isn't appropriate, you could create a custom role definition as @4c74356b41 wrote in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix the issue:

1.You just need to assign an [`Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#owner) role to your account in the vnet scope.

Let your admin user(the account login the portal need the `Owner` role in the vnet), navigate to the vnet mentioned in the error in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> add the account in the error as an `Owner`, for more details, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal#add-a-role-assignment).
After assigning your account to the vnet, you will be able to create the aks.

In this case, the [custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) menioned by others is **meaningless**. Once the user gets the `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` permission, he can assign himself with any role he want, including the `Owner` role. So for security issues, it does not help.

2.If it is not allowed you to assign your account as `Owner` to the vnet in your case, here is a better way. You can let your admin user(the account has an `Owner` in the vnet) add the service principal which you configured in the `Authentication` step(not select the `create new` option) as a `Network Contributor` to the vnet, then when you create the aks, it also works with no error.

If you did not have a service principal, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application) to create it.